# ajax request working in Postman, not in code

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, rest, postman

I have a web application making an ajax request to a server in node.js, however at the request, I always receive an error in the server console:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0

However in Postman, I send the same request and it goes through just fine. I'm so sure that there's something wrong in my ajax request, but I've been working on this for days and I can't figure out what.

Here's the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "/insert/image_data",
    method:"post",
    data: {
        tags: tag,
        cats: cat
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(res){
        console.log(res);
    },
    error: function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Here's the server handler:

```
app.post("/insert/image_data", function(req, res){
    let imageData = req.body;
    console.log("/insert/image_data route reached");
    console.log("--> imageData = ", prettyjson.render(imageData));

    res.status(200).send("Req GOOD");
});
```

Comment: Check the response text of the request in the console. That error implies what's coming back is not valid JSON - it looks like plain text from your Node sample.

Comment: see if you need to JSON.stringify 'tag' OR/AND 'cat' inside data

Comment: Is the data in the request valid JSON -  would something like this work?`data: JSON.stringify({ "tags": "tag", "cats": "cat" })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the advice from the comments, the problem was solved by using JSON.stringify to convert the request data into valid JSON formatting. Here is the working code:

```js
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "/insert/image_data",
    method:"post",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        tags: tag,
        cats: cat
    }),
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(res){
        console.log(res);
    },
    error: function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Credit to @gargkshitiz and @DannyDainton for the above solution.